# User Privileges in Sharepoint's Calendar

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-calendar

Is it possible for a user to just add an event in Sharepoint's Calendar? I know there are site and list permissions but I would want to setup a privilege wherein a user can add an event but cannot edit and delete others' events. Meaning, there will be lock permissions per user. If he/she is not the author of the event created, then he/she cannot edit and delete it. Please advise. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Create and Edit access**.

Check option: ***Create items and edit items that were created by the user***

Comment: Hi Nadeem Yousuf, thank you for your reply. I just tried it and it worked but not what I was expecting. I need to edit the permission per event just to change the privileges of the users. Is there anyway to make it automatically? Author should be the only one that can edit the event item? So what I did, I went to Calendar -> List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Under Create and Edit Access, I selected the option: Create items and edit items that were created by the user. Now, I have 2 user accounts: Admin (Full Control and User1 (Read & Write). Admin created an event but User1 can still edit.

Comment: So what I did, I clicked on the Manage Permission per event item in the calendar just to restrict User1 from editing it.